# Best way to create a xcode layouts grid

Tags: layout, xcode6, constraints

I am really new with xcode, I feel confortable using Android Studio and the way to work with Layouts and FrameLayouts. How can I achieve this distribution, of buttons?

I tried with each button as an elemnt . Can be the buttons be inside a view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to Xcode as well but let me give it a try. 
You can create a horizontal stack view, indeed 4 of them, one per row, and add your buttons inside it. This stack views will contain two buttons each. 
Then, you can join them all together creating a vertical stack view of the 4 horizontal stack views, thus creating a whole stack, where all your buttons live. [Here I created a calculator keypad using this exact method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnOkV.png)